# ASP.NET MVC Html.PagedListPager Not Working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

MyController:

```
    public ActionResult Index(String SearchString, int? page)
    {
        var query = from _mytable in _MyDataContext.MyTables select _mytable;

        int pageSize = 10;              // will only contain 10 products max because of the pageSize
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);   // if no page was specified in the querystring, default to the first page (1)

        PagedList.PagedList<MyTables> models = new PagedList.PagedList<Anlagen>(query, pageNumber, pageSize);

        return View(models);
    }
```

MyView, last line:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { ViewBag.SearchString, page}))
```

I don't know why, but the only pagination is:
«|‹|1|›|»

Calling the page with "?SearchString=hello&page=2" works well with results, but with the same pagination:
«|‹|1|›|»

here is my search form:

```
<form action="@Url.Action("Index", "Anlagen")" method="get" role="search" class="navbar-form-custom">
    <div class="form-group input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="suchen..." id="SearchString" name="SearchString" value="@ViewBag.SearchString" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Just a copy from an working project, but in a new project it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to order your elements for `PagedList` to work properly. Adjust your LINQ to order your collection by some value, such as `Name` if that exists:

```
var query = from _mytable in _MyDataContext.MyTables orderby _mytable.Name select _mytable;
```

Comment: sorry, no, same result: «|‹|1|›|»

Comment: Could you show the HTML that's being generated for the pager? Also, are you using any styling / libraries that may inadvertently be causing some problems?

Comment: Dear Chase, sorry for my delay - months later, here is the HTML generated by the pager:

` 
    <div class="pagination-container">
  <ul class="pagination">
   <li class="active"><a>1</a></li>
   <li><a href="/Artikel?page=2">2</a></li>
   <li><a href="/Artikel?page=3">3</a></li>
   <li class="PagedList-skipToNext"><a href="/Artikel?page=2" rel="next">»</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
`

Answer (score -1):

```
    This is  best Solution for PAGEDLISTPAGER in mvc5 :

    @Html.PagedListPager(Model,Page => Url.Action("Index",new { Page,    SearchBy=Request.QueryString["SearchBy"],
    Search = Request.QueryString["Search"] }), new PagedListRenderOptions() {Display=PagedListDisplayMode.IfNeeded
    ,DisplayPageCountAndCurrentLocation=true,DisplayItemSliceAndTotal=true
     } )


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////Solution////////browser back button give problem in MVC when logout////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    I had this problem a while ago, disabling the cache for the entire application solved my problem, just add these line to the Global.asax.cs file

            protected void Application_BeginRequest()
            {
                Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));
                Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
            }
```